# MaterializeCSS Sidenav JQuery Not Functioning

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm attempting to implement the responsive navigation bar Materialize CSS provides. I'm having trouble with implementing the JQuery side of the feature. I'm unsure as to why but the JQuery used to implement the feature is not functioning.

I've made my issue reproducible [here](https://codepen.io/themasteredpanda/pen/yLYVwam).

The JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(() => {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
 });
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="home_container">
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <a href="#" class="sidenav-toggle" data-target="testSidenav"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li>Registered Bikes</li>
        <li>Investigations</li>
        <li>Reports</li>
        <li>Vulnerability Map</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<ul class="sidenav" id="testSidenav">
    <li>Registered Bikes</li>
    <li>Investigations</li>
    <li>Reports</li>
    <li>Vulnerability Map</li>
</ul>

<div name="content" class="row s12">
</div>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your code:

**1. `sidenav-toggle` is not a valid classname. Correct classname is `sidenav-trigger`**

**2. All nav li's (including sidenav) must have a nested anchor tag to get the correct spacing:**

```
<ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li><a href="#!">Registered Bikes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Investigations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Reports</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Vulnerability Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

Fixed codepen [here.](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/abvBxrP?editors=1010)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="home_container">
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="testSidenav"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#!">Registered Bikes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Investigations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Vulnerability Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <ul class="sidenav" id="testSidenav">
        <li><a href="#!">Registered Bikes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Investigations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Vulnerability Map</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div name="content" class="row s12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Always use the markup from the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#mobile-collapse).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `<ul>` tag and change the anchor `<a>` tag class to `.sidenav-trigger`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="home_container">
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="testSidenav"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

        </div>
    </nav>


    <ul class="sidenav" id="testSidenav">
        <li>Registered Bikes</li>
        <li>Investigations</li>
        <li>Reports</li>
        <li>Vulnerability Map</li>
    </ul>

    <div name="content" class="row s12">
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want to test it on different screens, use the browsers inspect element to change screens